# Android Unsupported key size: 3 bytes on decrypt text

Tags: java, android, encryption

I have simple `json` object as:

**json:**

```
{
  "bookInfo": {
    "type": "book",
    "onvan": "کتاب دو",
    "tadvin": "دفتر",
    "nasher": "بوستان",
    "nobat": "اول",
    "shabek": "1100",
    "gheymat": "2000 تومان",
    "tasvirData": ""
  }
}
```

after `encryption` that on `c#` with `123` key, i have this result:

```
hlAkzlLeVE3JdYrk61dy8901K2tXWqx5qxYd1t8zVSZzx12lD6nxqZRlPRI8yX8PECxaHJ5zdueY0/A0J7Lxxlv2DHvdI/H+Qu2bsQI6X/Qc6ISwlY7Q6c0IiwWtKuFm5f8BC9wNSSqPXkBM7J+hwEtHUBAoh+IMzxNXvnA/hZIp3R2FznX4cdJhs4Lnm003WLGiKwJ1fEgzUl55WKBIh2dMwQwqpTlNmLFIo6ovlJYMt4DTaoeET+VAhHcGtX1u10910EZ1hCqb1pcspE1SPQ==
```

now when I try to `decrypt` that with `123` key I get this **error**:

```
Unsupported key size: 3 bytes
```

**EncryptUtils class:**

```
public class EncryptUtils {
    public static SecretKey generateKey(String mySecret) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        return new SecretKeySpec(mySecret.getBytes(), "AES");
    }

    public static byte[] encryptMsg(String message, SecretKey secret)
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidParameterSpecException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Cipher cipher = null;
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return cipherText;
    }

    public static String decryptMsg(byte[] cipherText, SecretKey secret)
            throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidParameterSpecException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Cipher cipher = null;
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret);
        String decryptString = new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText), "UTF-8");
        return decryptString;
    }
}
```

and this is my **decrypt code:**

```
String mySecret="123";
SecretKey secretKey = EncryptUtils.generateKey(mySecret);
JSONObject bookObject = new JSONObject(EncryptUtils.decryptMsg(bookContent.getBytes("UTF-8"), secretKey));
```

Comment: The byte value of `123` is not a valid AES key. Valid AES keys are 128, 196 or 256 bit long. If your C# code allows this key, it's due to some kind of undesirable defaulting.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen then which word can be used

Comment: AES don't use words as key, it uses binary keys of the length described. When you do stuff like `mySecret.getBytes()` to get a key from a string you are in effect reducing the key strength considerable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the string you are passing in to the hexToBytes function is Base64 encoded, it's not a hex string, so reading the first two characters as an integer causes an exception.

Change the line in decrypt to this:

```
String decryptString = new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText), "UTF-8");
```

To:

```
String decryptString= cipher.doFinal(Base64.decode(cipherText,Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Happy coding!!